# Put UIImageView with all Supported Resolutions in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint, xcode-storyboard

I want trying to place two different UIImageView at different position in my iOS project using Storyboard. In one resolution, I can able to set this properly but if I check into other resolution then its not looking properly.

Definitely I am new in iOS application development so making small mistakes.

I have actually make my layout and graphics in iPhone8 Plus resolution and here is what I have designed page in Storyboard.

[image]

Its looking proper as per my design layout but as I switched my layout say in iPhone5s then I got horrible result.
Please check below image:

[image]

As per my best understanding, I have set few constraints too. That you can see in both images. At present I just want to worries about header and footer logo UIImageView's scaling and positioning. If these two Views get solved then I will manage other Views too.

**EDIT:**

Here you have Footer Constraints:

[image]

@1x,@2x and @3x image resources already exist in project but as per my thinking its not get detected.

[image]

In terms of creating UI screen, I have followed reverse path. Actually I have designed graphics in 1080x1920 resolution so its my @3x and then I have cutting down size of each object respectively for @2x and @1x resources.

Please give me some help into this.

Comment: Start with your `FooterView` and `MainFooterLogo` ... what constraints have you set for those two elements?

Comment: Please check friends, my edited section of question based on your responses.

Comment: OK --- you haven't shown any constraints on your `FooterView`?

Comment: In my question if you check last second image then its showing you footer logo and view related constraints... still anything missing then let me know.

Comment: It shows that you have your `MainFooterLogo` constrained leading and trailing to your `FooterView`... but no height or top/bottom constraints. And, it doesn't show any constraints for `FooterView` to **its** superview.

Answer (score 0):

set the size of image in 1x and add the image in 3x format, for example your image name is xyz.png then it will saved as xyz@3x.png and xcode will automatically use this image on your app. you just have to calculate the size of the image in 1x set it to the view and everything will work.
Please check this and let me know in case it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set the constraints for your logo UIImageView's like this:

For logo_main:

top=20 (your value), bottom=20, leading=20, and trailing=20

[image]

For MainFooterLogo:

top=0, bottom=0, leading=8, and trailing=8

[image]

and set UIImageView's Content Mode to Aspect Fit:

[image]

Your problem will be solved but you need more constraint and may be a UIScrollView for your middle container view.